# Error: redefinition of class [class name]

Tags: c++, error-handling, include-guards

I have seen this error a lot, and there're a lot of questions about it here, but now I really don't know what to do.

User.h

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
#endif // USER_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class User
{
private:
    struct Accounts {string user, password, name;} accounts[2];
    void setAccounts();

public:
    int Access(string user, string password);
    bool online;

    User();
    ~User();
};
```

User.cpp

```
#include "User.h"

#include <iostream>

User::User() {/* data */}
User::~User() {/* data */}

void User::setAccounts()
{
    accounts[0].user = "user01";
    accounts[0].password = "pw01";
    accounts[0].name = "hi";

    accounts[1].user = "user02";
    accounts[1].password = "pw02";
    accounts[1].name = "hi2";
}

int User::Access(string user, string password)
{
    unsigned short int i;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        if (user.compare(this->accounts[i].user) == 0 and password.compare(this->accounts[i].password) == 0)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I've used even `#pragma once` and it still not recognizing the class.
What do I do?

**@edit:** I moved down `#endif // USER_H` and now the class has been recognized, but the constructor method still missed.

> "error: multiple definitions of 'User::User()'"

Comment: Your include guard does... well... nothing.

Comment: #pragma once should be ok though, if you get rid of the #if .. #endif guard

Comment: assuming the #pragma once was put in the correct place :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should place `#endif // USER_H` at the end of the header file. Only the content between `#ifndef` and `#endif` is protected to be included multiple times.

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class User
{
private:
    struct Accounts {string user, password, name;} accounts[2];
    void setAccounts();

public:
    int Access(string user, string password);
    bool online;

    User();
    ~User();
};

#endif // USER_H
```

**EDIT**

You should not include `User.cpp`. Only header file should be included.

Comment: Still not working. The compiler says that there're multiple definitions of User::User(). It still being a compiler problem.

Comment: @Chisté Did you `#include "User.cpp"` somewhere?

Comment: Oh zzzzz, there is. Another noob mistake hauyh21ijksajhyghui thx

Comment: @Chisté Yes, only header file should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Move `#endif // USER_H` to the bottom of the file?

Comment: Still not working. The compiler says that there're multiple definitions of User::User(). It still being a compiler problem.